# Nesting variables in a React JSX string

Tags: reactjs, sass, jsx

I am modifying this code stanza

```
<div className={`${css['red']} ${css['blue']}`}>
    ...
</div>
```

to this, changing the `blue` string to a variable

```
var colorVariable = 'blue'
<div className={`${css['red']} ${css[{colorVariable}]}`}>
    ...
</div>
```

But this doesn't take any effect whatsoever. Neither does `${css['{colorVariable}']}`.

Doing `${css[${colorVariable}]}` results in a error.

What is the right way to next JSX variables in a string?

Edit: 
The css object is defined as follows

```
import css from 'assets/style.scss'
```

Comment: How you define the css object?

Comment: The css object is defined as `import css from 'assets/style.scss'`

Comment: Check this link https://codesandbox.io/s/m9mv2v6m4x

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link, I understand the situation much better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the JSX syntax once you're already inside of the template literal.

You should be using something more along the lines of:

```
`${css['red']} ${css[colorVariable]}`
```